# Create Moodle activities programmatically

Tags: php, moodle

Does anyone know if it’s possible to add an activity programmatically to a course in Moodle?

I was thinking to maybe use the class `module_add_instance()` from the lib.php of my custom plugin...

e.g.

```
function feedback_add_instance(stdClass $mod) {
   global $DB;

   $newmodule->timecreated = time();

   // You may have to add extra stuff in here.

   $newmodule->id = $DB->insert_record('exams', $newmodule);

   unicexams_grade_item_update($newmodule);

   return $newmodule->id;
}
```

But then again: What is the `$mod` variable? What does it contain and how to construct it?

Does anyone has knowledge on the subject? Or something to advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add_moduleinfo()` would be better. Below is something I use for facetoface.

To get started, edit `/course/modedit.php` then temporarily add the following, then add the required activity via the front end - this will give you a list of most of the properties required:

```
var_dump($fromform);
die();
$fromform = add_moduleinfo($fromform, $course, $mform);
```

Code to create a facetoface instance

```
$newfacetoface = new stdClass();
$newfacetoface->name = $facetoface->facetofacename;
$newfacetoface->intro = '';
$newfacetoface->thirdparty = '';
$newfacetoface->display = 6;
$newfacetoface->approvalreqd = 0;
$newfacetoface->selfapprovaltandc = $strmgr->get_string('selfapprovaltandccontents', 'facetoface', $facetoface->langcode);
$newfacetoface->allowcancellationsdefault = 1;
$newfacetoface->cancellationscutoffdefault = 0;
$newfacetoface->multiplesessions = 1; // Allow multiple sessions.
$newfacetoface->managerreserve = '0';
$newfacetoface->maxmanagerreserves = '1';
$newfacetoface->reservecancel = '1';
$newfacetoface->reservecanceldays = '1';
$newfacetoface->reservedays = '2';
$newfacetoface->showoncalendar = '1';
$newfacetoface->usercalentry = '1';
$newfacetoface->shortname = '';
$newfacetoface->published = $facetoface->visible;
$newfacetoface->branches = $facetoface->branches;
$newfacetoface->visible = $facetoface->visible;
$newfacetoface->cmidnumber = $facetoface->facetofaceid;
$newfacetoface->idnumber = $facetoface->facetofaceid;
$newfacetoface->groupmode = '0';
$newfacetoface->availabilityconditionsjson = '{"op":"&","c":[],"showc":[]}';
$newfacetoface->completionunlocked = 1;
$newfacetoface->completionunlockednoreset = 0;
$newfacetoface->completion = COMPLETION_TRACKING_AUTOMATIC;
$newfacetoface->completionstatusrequired = '{"100":1}';
$newfacetoface->completionexpected = 0;
$newfacetoface->course = $course->id;
$newfacetoface->coursemodule = 0;
$newfacetoface->section = 1;
$newfacetoface->module = $moduleid;
$newfacetoface->modulename = 'facetoface';
$newfacetoface->instance = 0;
$newfacetoface->add = 'facetoface';
$newfacetoface->update = 0;
$newfacetoface->return = 0;
$newfacetoface->sr = 0;

$moduleinfo = add_moduleinfo($newfacetoface, $course);
```

Comment: Great I had no idea that add_moduleinfo() exists.

Moodle has so many functions and no documentation!

I will try and report back with a solution. THanks

Comment: I'm newbie in moodle , i struggling exact this problem. i wanna to make quiz using api, i tried many ways , I've read all the moodle documentation but still its not solve . could you please help me. or explain what have you done for this problem. thank you @Christos312

Comment: I'm newbie in moodle , i struggling exact this problem. i wanna to make quiz using api, i tried many ways , I've read all the moodle documentation but still its not solve . could you please help me. or explain what have you done for this problem. thank you @Russell England